# Proving condition on non-degenerate zeros of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

> Could someome help me solve the following question?
>
> - Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a $C^\infty$ manifold and $TM \subset \mathbb{R^{2n}}$ its fiber tangent.
> - Let $v: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ a $C^\infty$ vector field on $M$.
> - Let $M\times\{0\}=\{(x,u) \in TM:u=0 \}$, a $C^\infty$ sub-manifold of $TM$ diffeomorphic to $M$.
>
> We are also given the application: $f_v: M \rightarrow TM$, $f_v(x)=(x,v(x))$ with $f_v(M)=M_v$.
>
> I'd like to show that, assuming that $x$ is a zero of $v$  (i.e. $v(x)=0$), then $x$ is a non-degenerate zero of $v$ if and only if:
>
> $T_{(x,0)}(M\times\{0\})+T_{(x,0)}M_v =T_{(x,0)}TM$

I have already shown that:

- $M_v$ is a $C^\infty$ sub-manifold of $TM$, diffeomorphic to $M$.
- if $x$ is a zero of $v$, then $Dv(x)(T_xM)\subset T_xM$ and $(x,v(x))\in M\times\{0\}$
- if a zero of $v$ is non-degenerate, then $Dv(x): T_xM\rightarrow T_xM$ is bijective and the non-degenerate zeros of $v$ are isolated points

but I have difficulty concluding. Thank you.

Comment: You have done everything you need. Your last item reduces to this: In $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$, the tangent space to the graph of $v(x)$ at $(x,0)$ is the graph of the derivative $A=Dv(x)$, and we have $\Bbb R^n\times\{0\} + \text{graph}(A) = \Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ if and only if $A$ is an invertible linear map.

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed! Thank you very much.